# any number of any type of arguments

Tags: c++

I have a function which can take any number of any type of arguments(generic arguments).

I don't want to use va_arg stuffs and variadic template arguments is not supported in my compiler. I use boost library.

Can anyone suggest me how to implement this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use `va_args` and don't want to use a decently recent compiler that supports variadic templates (like the free and open-source `GCC` or `Clang` compilers), there's no way to achieve that. If you can live with an upper limit in the number of arguments, you can use `Boost.Preprocessor` to define functions that take 0 to `N` arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You could also cheat, by passing in an array of void pointers,

```
void func(void**args);
```

and require the last be a Null, or pass in a vector,

```
void func(std::vector<void*> args);
```

But you're exposing your API to abuse and untraceable runtime errors, and any decent code review will require you to go away and redesign your code properly.

Comment: You may consider Boost.Any to replace `void *`.